# Can't update TextView and ImageView in Toolbar

Tags: android, layout, toolbar

I want to set avatar of user and his name **dynamicly in toolbar**, but it doesn't work. I've tried to bind it with ButterKnife, and simple by View.findViewById nothing helped. Actually views are **not null** even with ButterKnife so I have no idea why it doesn't work. But i found out that if there is **only one View in Toolbar without layout**, View updates easly.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium_large"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

init

```
...

@BindView(R.id.avatar)
ImageView mAvatar;
@BindView(R.id.name)
TextView mName;

...

private void initToolbar(String baseUrl, String name) {
    Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(baseUrl)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(mAvatar);

    mName.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code which sets the image/text?

Comment: @FierceFox added

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it without Butterknife like this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
ImageView image = v.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
```